QLineEdit adding extra '\' from text()
I'm entering a string in QLineEdit as:
SIM VFB ALL\.DataProcCycle\.EmGenObjectList\.aObject\[.*\]\.Kinematic\.fDistX

Then I'm reading the text and creating an INI file with QSettings.
My code is as below:
QSettings* settings = new QSettings(m_taskPath + SignalSettingsData::SIGNALSETTINGS_FILENAME, QSettings::IniFormat);
settings->beginGroup(m_RadarSignalEditorUI->projectNameLbl->text());
for(QLineEdit* lineedit : m_RadarSignalEditorUI->scrollAreaWidgetContents->findChildren<QLineEdit*>())
{
    if(lineedit && !lineedit->text().isEmpty())
     {
          QString objName = lineedit->objectName();
          objName = objName.remove("lineEdit_");
          QString textentered = lineedit->text();
          qInfo()<<__FUNCTION__<<textentered;
//            textemtered = lineedit->text().toUtf8().constData();
//            qInfo()<<__FUNCTION__<<textemtered;
          settings->setValue(objName, textentered);
     }
}
settings->endGroup();
settings->sync();

But double backslashes are being added. One extra \.
In the UI it's ok, but in debug statements also \\, and in the INI file also.


Same in the INI file, also:

Forward slashes can't be used. These are signal urls.
How do I get the proper string from the lineedit->text() in the INI file like below?


\ is treated as a special character in an INI file, it has to be escaped as \\. The QSettings documentation says: "Although backslash is a special character in INI files, most Windows applications don't escape backslashes (\) in file paths: windir = C:\Windows. QSettings always treats backslash as a special character and provides no API for reading or writing such entries."
